# How do I execute python script on a file in the same command line?

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, command-line, io

I have a python script which convert a text file to another format. I want to do this way: *python convert.py filename* .

How could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is take *command line arguments*: http://www.diveintopython.net/scripts_and_streams/command_line_arguments.html

Those docs should help you out, but if you google that phrase and python you'll find plenty of examples!